# What is the role of the AngularJS transformRequest function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can anyone tell me what is the role of this function in angularjs? I tried it in the http post method to webservice.

**here is my code .**

```
transformRequest: function(obj) {
    var str = [];
    for(var p in obj)
    str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
    return str.join("&");
}
```

Without this function the code will not be executed because the form will be posted with a null variable.

Comment: it's not really obvious without seeing what your data looks like and what your server expects, but all this code does is convert your object into a URI encoded string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function adds all the parameters in the object passed with their value as a string which you can use in a GET.

For example:

```
{
   foo: bar
   bla: blabla
}
```

will be transformed to `foo=bar&bla=blabla`